# The model being used for the service elasticbeanstalk is missing the serviceId metadata property

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, ebcli

Receiving ERROR:

```
MissingServiceIdError :: The model being used for the service elasticbeanstalk is missing the serviceId metadata property, which is required.
```

whenever trying to run the command `eb init`.
installed the awsebcli with the command `python3 -m pip install awsebcli --upgrade --user`.

```
eb -- version : EB CLI 3.10.2 (Python 3.6.0)
aws -- version: aws-cli/1.14.6 Python/2.7.18 Linux/4.9.20-10.30.amzn1.x86_64 botocore/1.8.10
```

need support. thank you

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to update to a more recent version of EB CLI - 3.14.6 has a fix for this.

See https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/issues/3550 for more details.

Comment: What worked for me was the combination mentioned in [this comment](https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/issues/3550#issuecomment-419608744): `awscli==1.16.9 awsebcli==3.14.4`